# Multimeter Giving Wrong Temperature Probe Readings

Tags: temperature, multimeter

I want to ask a question about my multimeter, it's new but when i plug in the temperature cable - red to VOhm, black to COM and turn to tempreture it displays temp of period(-886°C/-900°C), and when i plug off the cables it displays the normal temperature of the room (e.g. 18°C). What is the problem and how can I fix it. my multimeter is DT9208A

Comment: Check your user manual. Most photos that appear with a Google search of "DT9208A" show a "Degrees C" icon on the "mA" terminal. Try red on "mA" and black on "COM".

Comment: Show exactly how/what  you plug off and where you read.. and exact sensor

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Connect to K+, K-
then select mA 'C

Note the common for temp sensor is **mA K-** current

COM = nyet
*COM не используется для датчика температуры*

Comment: It would seem there are [some multimeters for sale](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DT9208A-Portable-Digital-Multimeter-AC-DC-Voltage-Current-Resistance-Capacitance-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Multi-Tester-LCD-Display/32799117322.html) labelled "DT9208A" which differ from the image you've posted.

Comment: so it seems , It would make a great challenge for all of us to describe it's circuit in 25 words or less https://i.stack.imgur.com/viSLN.png

Comment: Tony could (describe it's circuit in 25 words or less) because he speaks in Mathematics;-) That's a complement.